# acts_as_follower - missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to add acts_as_follower gem into a rails app I am developing but I always seem to get an exception error that says users id is nil. Browsing through every tutorial I found on Google, none seemed to fix my problem.

Users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def follow
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    current_user.follow(@user)
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def unfollow
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    current_user.stop_following(@user)
    redirect_to :back
  end

end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  acts_as_follower
  acts_as_followable
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
    acts_as_followable
end
```

Routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :posts

  devise_for :users
  root 'page#index'
  get '/users/:id' => 'page#profile'
  get 'page/feed'
  get 'page/home'

  resources :users do
    member do
      get :follow
      get :unfollow
    end
  end
end
```

The link that I am adding to the profile's view:

```
<%= link_to "Follow", follow_user_path(@user)%>
```

Did I write something wrong in the routes? Because it worked when I tested it in the console. The errors started showing I tried to actually make it functional for users.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message please

Comment: The most likely explanation is that `@user` is nil - and that you instead intended to use the local variable `user`.

Comment: I tried using both. if i use `user` it'll through an undefined local variable instead

Comment: @Turk error is `No route matches {:action=>"follow", :controller=>"posts", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]`